# In R, can out of bounds indexing return NAs on matrices, like it does on vectors?

Tags: r, indexing

I would like an out of bounds subscript on a matrix in R to return NAs instead of an error, like it does on vectors.

```
> a <- 1:3
> a[1:4]
[1]  1  2  3 NA
> b <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> b[1:4, 1]
Error: subscript out of bounds
>
```

So I would have liked it to return:

```
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Right now I am doing this with ifelse tests to see if the index variables exist in the rownames but on large data structures this is taking quite a bit of time. here is an example:

```
s <- split(factors, factors$date) # split so each date has its own list
names <- last(s)[[1]]$bond # names of bonds that we want
cdmat <- sapply(names, function(n)
                sapply(s, function(x)
                       if(n %in% x$bond) x[x$bond == n, column] else NA))
```

where factors is an xts with about 250 000 rows. So it's taking about 15 seconds and that's too long for my application.

The reason this is important is that each list element I am applying this to has a different length, but I need to output a matrix with equal length columns as a result of the sapply. I don't want another list out with different length elements.

Comment: I think you should explain what your *actual* problem is. From here, I seem to get the idea that you've a list output from `sapply` from which you want a matrix filling missing values with `NA`. If so, `rbind.fill` function from `plyr` package might just do the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have just realised that if I take the column I want and turn it into a vector, this works perfectly. So:

```
> b[, 1][1:4]
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Comment: If `column` is always an integer, you were never getting matrices from that: `x[x$bond == n, column]`. Since `drop=TRUE` by default, those were always vectors. All you needed to do was `length(b) <- 4`.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I am sometimes selecting non-contiguous names from each list. Adding a length override would just pad with NAs whereas I need the NAs in the right places.

Comment: My point remains. You were not getting matrices, so you needed a solution that worked on vectors.

Comment: But.... s <- split(DEfactors, DEfactors$date); tail(sapply(s, class), 1) returns "data.frame". What am I misunderstanding? Because what I then need to do is index data frame rows by a pre-existing vector of names, and where those names are not in the row names of the data frame, return an NA, not an out of bounds error.

Comment: sigh. I'm quite sure that `is.matrix(b[, 1])` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: yes that is quite obvious. My simplified example was too simplified. The point is much more about the more complex example. Please try to answer that.

Comment: Make it reproducible then. At the moment your answer appears to indicate you have a satisfactory solution. I was just attempting clarification.